# Java - Adding columns and data into existing JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have a small java application in which i want to put some data and it's columns inside an existing JTable.

So here is my columns and data;

```
String[][] data; // this object gets it's contents from another function
String[] columns={"Name","Value"}; //these are the columns that should be added to JTable
```

So what should i do to add and see the data inside "existing" JTable? I don't want to create a dynamic JTable.

**EDIT:**

I wrote this into the function that fills my variables above. How can i refresh my JTable after that?

```
tblSonuc=new JTable(data,columns);
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Where is the data coming from that you want to insert?

Comment: this data comes from another custom class, which is created by me.

Comment: There is a function which calls another class and that class fills my "data" and "columns" object.

Comment: What is the data though? Is it just fields in a class representing each column or is it data already stored like in a `2D array` already. What triggers this data do be inserted into the table?

Comment: It's a data already stored. Let's call it's coming from "Class A". My form class is "Class B". There is function in Class B, which creates an object from Class A and stores this 2D array to this "String[][] data" thing directly.

Comment: But I mean Class A is just contains fields right, like `firstName` lastName` and then in `Class B` you want to create `Class A` ojbects and load them to the table? Like you just want the data in the table to be `firstName` and `lastName` right?

Comment: No. this string array is already created and filled in class A. I just take it from A and put into my new variable in class B.

Comment: See My **EDIT** below

Comment: Check my EDIT at the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add rows dynamically, use a `TableModel`. A simple already implemented one is `DefaultTableModel`. Just set the model to your `JTable`

```
String[] columns = {"Column 1","Column 2"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0); <-- 0 is number of rows
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

The just use the `addRow` method of the model, which takes either a `Object[]` or a `Vector`. So you could just do this

```
Object[] rowData { data1, data2 };
model.addRow(rowData);
```

---

See more at [**How to Use Tables**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [**DefaultTableModel**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for more methods.

---

**EDIT**

> "this string array is already created and filled in class A. I just take it from A and put into my new variable in class B"

If you want to add the data from the 2D array from the class, just loop through it and add it to the model

```
A a = new A();
String[][] students = a.getDtudents();

for (String[] row : students) {
    model.addRow(row):
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If you're using GUI Builder, the model for `JTable` is `DefaultTableModel` by default. To set the setting for the model, just

1. Select/highlight the table in the design view
2. Go to the properties panel and click the <kbd>...</kbd> at the right of the **model** property.
3. In the dialog you can set the number of rows to 0 and set your column headers.

Now say you want to access the model in a `actionPerformed` Just do this

```
private void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionPerformed e) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    model.setRorCount(0);
    A a = new A();
    String[][] students = a.getStudents();
    for (String[] row : students) {
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it.Answer may be right but the Jtable isn't refreshed. There is still old columns and data.

Comment: You didn't mention you wanted to remove old data. Just use `model.setRowCount(0);`

Comment: sho what if my jtable is just a drag-drop object, not a new one?

Comment: What do you mean a drag and drop object? You mean you're using GUI Builder?

Comment: Yes, this JTable is added from toolbox, not dynamically.

Comment: Ok gimme 5 minutes then see my answer.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem but i think my ide has bugs, i can't see even a dynamically created JTable. So thanks for your efforts, marking it as solution.

Comment: It because of the `GroupLayout` It's difficult to dynamically add new components. You either need to allocate space for it with an empty panel, and just add components to that empty panel dynamically or you can use a `CardLayout`

Comment: I created an empty panel and tried to create a dynamic jtable inside it. But it didn't work. I think it's because of "initComponents()" function inside constructor function.

Comment: 1) Why do you need a dynamic table in the first place? 2) Where in your code are you trying to add the table 3) initComponents is not the problem. 4) After adding components dynamically to a container, you need to call the container's `revailidate()` and `repaint()`. So `jPanel.revalidate(); jPanel.repaint()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46946/discussion-between-aloneinthedark-and-peeskillet)

Answer (score 0):

Fill your data[][] with data you need, do the same with your column[], then put it into constructor. Something like this:

```
String[][] data = {{"Row1Col1","Row1Col2"},{"Row2Col1","Row2Col2"}};
String[] columns = {"Column 1","Column 2"};
JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
```

Comment: My data won't be static, this data comes from a function.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark then you can use table.setValueAt(row, column, data) changing your data where you need.